# How to index text files in apache solr

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

I have some information in a text file. I want to index it on solr. What should be the procedure. Any tool that can be used for indexing in solr ? Please guide me in details as I am not familiar with solr too mutch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refer you to [Solr DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) Page, it has a comprehensive tutorial on how to import data from various source. Importing text files is under [FileDataSource](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FileDataSource)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the plain text into CSV file. You can then use the CSV file uploading process to index data in Solr. Check the documentation here for more configurations
[Here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV)

Comment: Should I use apache tika for indexing?

Comment: what is the structure of your text file? What kind of data are you putting in this file?

Comment: basically I have some images and in text file I have some information about that image e.g some text apearing in image etc. Now I want to index this text file in solr so that when I search for that specific text, I get that image in result.

Comment: Ok. IMO using apache tika would be cumbersome. In that you will have to write your own parser for this file structure and the overhead of its setup. Also, tika is mostly preferred to extract data from complex file structures like PDF, ppt. etc. From what I understand, if you can have the text file generated as CSV in first place, you have very little to do further to index in Solr.

Comment: Can you guide me how to write a parser for a text file